# Finding a ring homomorphism...

Tags: abstract-algebra

Find a ring $R$ and an explicit, onto ring homomorphism $f: \Bbb Z[x] \rightarrow R$ s.t. there is an element $a \in R$ s.t. $5a=1$.

I was thinking use $R=\Bbb Z/4 \Bbb Z$ and sending the polynomial's constant term $a_0$ to $a_0$ $mod4$. This is definitely onto, but is it a ring homomorphism? I believe so. And $5$ is $1$ here so there is no issue there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: What if you just made $x$ do what you want $a$ do? How would you accomplish this?

Comment: mod out by the ideal generated by $5x-1$?

Comment: Absolutely! Does that work?

Comment: I think so! Thanks!

Comment: @AnthonyVasaturo Any quotient of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is simply generated as a ring (generated by the image of $x$). So, if you want to create a ring that is simply generated and has an inverse of $5$, why not just throw in the inverse of $5$! Namely, consider the ring $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{5}]\subseteq\mathbb{Q}$. This is precisely the ring you suggested.

Comment: See, I didn't realize that fact about the quotients you just stated.

Comment: @AnthonyVasaturo Well, hopefully it makes sense now!